# Import Java Code in Clojure - Protocol Buffer

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have a JAR with a class Proto$Event.class (compiled from Protocol Buffer). Now I want to use it in a Clojure Project.

I include the JAR on my clojure project following [this steps](https://gist.github.com/edipofederle/4e4eff242e53a56c4165).

But I am not be able to run this code in clojure:

```
(ns protocolbuf-test.core
  (:import
   (com.foo.bar Proto$Event)))
```

the error:

```
1. Unhandled java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
   com.foo.bar.Proto$Event
```

Any Suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: `:import` works only inside the `ns` macro - `(ns foo.core (:import (com.foo.bar Proto$Event)))`. At the REPL, you can use the `import` function and you need to quote the list - `(import '(com.foo.bar Proto$Event))`

Comment: Sorry @ez121sl. I use ```ns``` macro. Just omited here....

Answer (score 0):

Solved!.

probably something wrong with JAR version in my local repo. I Just remove the local repo (repo directory inside my Clojure project), then add the JAR again.

Thanks